# I'm getting an illegal start of expression when I declare my variable with static in it?

Tags: java, static

```
static int basketballPlayer; 
static int activebasketballPlayers;
static int legendbasketballPlayers;
```

Illegal start of expression

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: where in the source file are these declarations? What language are you trying to use? What is the exact error message?

Comment: You should also post a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just an isolated code sample makes for a very unclear question.

Comment: I bet it's Java and those declarations appear in a method .. anyone want to take the bet? ;-)

Comment: @EmbattledSwag And you just assumed this is Java? If it isn't, this will get a bunch of answers that are completely unhelpful to OP.

Answer (score 2):

In Java the `static` modifier applies to *classes*, *fields* and *methods*. See [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) which briefly discusses the use of the modifier.

```
class Foo {
    static int foo; // okay - static applied to field
}
```

But `static` *cannot* be used with local variables in Java

```
class Bar {
    void x () {
        static int bar; // fail - static cannot be applied to local variables
    }
}
```

and the above results in the familiar compiler error:

```
error: illegal start of expression
    static int bar;
```

Comment: *In Java the static modifier only applies to fields and methods.*... That's weird, thought they were applicable to classes as well.

Comment: @JoshM Whoops, you're correct. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `static` when you're declaring fields at the start of a class. If you're trying to declare these within a method, you can't use static.

May I refer you to this, which should help you understand Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html